# How do I relate an alias to a recursive ID?

Tags: sql-server, alias, sql-server-2014, recursive-query

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
    stuID       INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    stuFName    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    stuLName    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    stuEmail    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT pk_student_stuID PRIMARY KEY (stuID) 
);

INSERT INTO student (stuFName, stuLName, stuEmail)
VALUES
('Billy-Bob', 'MacBeth', 'dragonSlayer@gmail.com'),
('Rob-Roy', 'MacGregor', 'rMacGregor1@yahoo.com'),
('Sweeny', 'MacSituation', 'EyeSwearInGaelic@yahoo.com'),
('Kim', 'MacDassian', 'kayDee@gmail.com'),
('Monte', 'MacHaggis', 'meanMonty01@yahoo.com');

CREATE TABLE course
(
    courseCode  CHAR(6),
    courseName  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT pk_course_courseCode PRIMARY KEY (courseCode) 
);

INSERT INTO course (courseCode,courseName) VALUES
('PHY200', 'Quantum Physics'),
('MAT100', 'Statistics'),
('BIO250', 'Biomechanics'),
('SOC100', 'Intro to Sociology'),
('PSY101', 'Human Perception');


CREATE TABLE  tutor_session
(
    tsID                INT         IDENTITY(1,1),
    tsMeetingDateTime   DATETIME2   NOT  NULL,
    tsLength            TINYINT     NOT NULL,
    tsMeetingConfirmed  BIT         DEFAULT 0,
    learnerID           INT         NOT NULL,
    tutorID             INT         NOT NULL,
    courseCode          CHAR(6)     NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT pk_tutorSession_tsID PRIMARY KEY(tsID),
CONSTRAINT fk_learner_tutorSession FOREIGN KEY(learnerID) REFERENCES student(stuID),
CONSTRAINT fk_tutor_tutorSession FOREIGN KEY(tutorID) REFERENCES student(stuID),
CONSTRAINT fk_course_tutorSession FOREIGN KEY(courseCode) REFERENCES course(courseCode)
);

INSERT INTO tutor_session (tsMeetingDateTime, tsLength, learnerID, tutorID, courseCode) VALUES
('2015-11-01 08:00AM', 2, 1, 2, 'PHY200'),
('2015-11-01 10:00AM', 1, 3, 2, 'MAT100'),
('2015-11-01 08:00AM', 2, 1, 2, 'PHY200'),
('2015-11-02 03:00PM', 1, 2, 1, 'BIO250'),
('2015-11-03 02:00AM', 3, 1, 2, 'SOC100'),
('2015-11-04 02:00AM', 3, 1, 2, 'SOC100'),
('2015-11-10 02:00AM', 1, 4, 2, 'PSY101'),
('2015-11-03 02:00AM', 1, 5, 2, 'PSY101');
```

This will input the same name in the first two columns, which is the 'Learner' name. What I want to do is relate the 'Tutor' alias to it's appropriate value.

[I'm trying to get an input identical to this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhhNU.png)

```
SELECT 
    tsID, stuFName + ' ' + stuLName AS 'Tutor', 
    stuFName + ' ' + stuLName AS 'Learner', 
    courseName, tsMeetingDateTime
FROM 
    tutor_session
JOIN 
    student ON tutor_session.learnerID = student.stuID
JOIN 
    course ON tutor_session.courseCode = course.courseCode
ORDER BY 
    courseName asc
```

Comment: join student twice. `join student as learner on .... join student as tutor on ...`

Answer (score 0):

What @MarcB said.  just join to the student table twice.. once for learner and again for tutor..  Use aliases on your joins to know which is which.

```
SELECT 
    tsID, 
    tutor.stuFName + ' ' + tutor.stuLName AS 'Tutor', 
    learner.stuFName + ' ' + learner.stuLName AS 'Learner', 
    courseName, 
    tsMeetingDateTime
FROM 
    tutor_session
JOIN 
    student as learner ON tutor_session.learnerID = learner.stuID
JOIN 
    student as tutor ON tutor_session.tutorID = tutor.stuID
JOIN 
    course ON tutor_session.courseCode = course.courseCode
ORDER BY 
    courseName ASC
```